# GWT openlayers, DrawFeature line style

Tags: java, gwt, openlayers, gwt-openlayers

I am using gwt openlayers to draw some linestrings on the map. I would like to change the draw feature line appearance. I noticed that PathHandler class has setStyle method, but setting style using this method does not change the line appearance.

```
private DrawFeature createDrawFeature() {
    DrawFeatureOptions options = new DrawFeatureOptions();
    options.onFeatureAdded(getStyle());
    PathHandler handler = new PathHandler();
    handler.setStyle(style);
    return new DrawFeature(layer, handler, options );
}
private Style getStyle() {
    Style style = new Style();
    style.setStrokeColor("#ffffff");
    style.setStrokeWidth(2.0);
    return style;
}
```

I was trying to set different style options but there was no effect.
Does anyone know how to change appearance of DrawFeature line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handler that does the drawing (Point, Path, or Polygon) is in charge if the style of your sketches (features before they are completed).

So to style the sketches you do :

```
    //Create a style. We want a blue dashed line.
    final Style drawStyle = new Style(); //create a Style to use
    drawStyle.setFillColor("white");
    drawStyle.setGraphicName("x");
    drawStyle.setPointRadius(4);
    drawStyle.setStrokeWidth(3);
    drawStyle.setStrokeColor("#66FFFF");
    drawStyle.setStrokeDashstyle("dash");

    //create a StyleMap using the Style
    StyleMap drawStyleMap = new StyleMap(drawStyle);

    //Create PathHanlderOptions using this StyleMap
    PathHandlerOptions phOpt = new PathHandlerOptions();
    phOpt.setStyleMap(drawStyleMap);   

    //Create DrawFeatureOptions and set the PathHandlerOptions (that have the StyleMap, that have the Style we wish)
    DrawFeatureOptions drawFeatureOptions = new DrawFeatureOptions();
    drawFeatureOptions.setHandlerOptions(phOpt);

    PathHandler pathHanlder = new PathHandler();

    // Create the DrawFeature control to draw on the map, and pass the DrawFeatureOptions to control the style of the sketch
    final DrawFeature drawLine = new DrawFeature(vectorLayer, pathHanlder, drawFeatureOptions);
    map.addControl(drawLine);
    drawLine.activate();
```

I also added an example to she showcase : http://demo.gwt-openlayers.org/gwt_ol_showcase/GwtOpenLayersShowcase.html?example=DrawFeature%20style%20example

Comment: Thanks, it works fine, but what about the final line(i mean when draw is done)? It still has old thin orange style.

Comment: @UP.
OK I found the way to achieve this using onFeatureAdded in drawfeature options
 public void onFeatureAdded(VectorFeature vectorFeature) {
  vectorFeature.setStyle(getStyle());
  vectorFeature.redrawParent();
 }

Comment: Falcon, that probably does work but is a little overboard.

You should just use the setStyle or setStyleMap method on the vectorlayer. That way you just need to set the style once on the layer.

Something like 

    Vector vectorLayer = new Vector("Vector layer");

    final Style drawStyle = new Style(); //create a Style to use
    drawStyle.setFillColor("white");
    drawStyle.setGraphicName("x");
    drawStyle.setPointRadius(4);
    drawStyle.setStrokeWidth(3);
    drawStyle.setStrokeColor("#66FFFF");
    drawStyle.setStrokeDashstyle("dash");
    
    vectorLayer.setStyle(drawStyle);